Is it possible to inject or blend parent background between child background and foreground?
I would like to alter parent element (only parent) in such way that it will affect its children background. I cannot change the code for the children though.
Visually parent background should be either inserted between child background and foreground or parent background should blend with child background.
Consider the following code -- you will notice the red color (parent background) is covered by yellow (children). I can easily blend backgrounds when changing blend mode on children, but as I wrote I cannot do this -- this has to be responsibility of parent.
And one more obstacle -- it should work for parent with display block and grid at least.
Is it possible at all? If yes, how?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>

    h1
    {
        z-index: 0;
        border: 1px green solid;
    }

    h1:nth-child(odd)
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .pane-bg
    {
        height: 8rem;
    }


    .indicator-bg
    {
        position: relative;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100%;

        background: radial-gradient(at top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), transparent 70%) 50% 0 / 50% 55px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        isolation: isolate;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        background-blend-mode: screen;
        z-index: 1;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pane-bg">
<div class="indicator-bg">
    <h1>QUHWFHUIWHFIUFHWNWKNFWEFWEFHUIFWHEUIHFUIHWUIFHWUIFEHUIWFHWNWFUIFUI</h1>
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    <h1> XXXXXXXXXXXX </h1>
    <h1> ala ma kota </h1>
    <h1> bardzo malego </h1>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



What I am really trying to achieve -- top and bottom scroll indicators for single scrolling container. Some time ago I "solved" this with a workaround -- by creating two containers and indicators were regular child elements of the outer container. Now I want to solve this the right way, with single container. This technique is copied from CSS Secrets by Lea Verou, the original code is here: https://dabblet.com/gist/20205b5fcdd834461e80
